# Sync _all_ music in Google Play Music to local storage

Tags: google-play-music

This might sound a little crazy, but I'd like to sync my entire Google Play Music collection to my external SD card on my Galaxy S5. Is there a setting in Google Play Music which will sync *everything*? I know I can specify where I'd like things to go, but is there a global sync all setting?

Comment: Is it currently downloaded into the internal memory? What do you mean 'everything'? Everything already downloaded? If you select 'External Storage' it will automatically move all downloaded music from internal to external and any future downloads to the External.

Comment: When you buy music from the play store, you wil be able to listen to on google music play, that allows you to sync your music on your phone but you can't have access to it in your phone storage or anything else. So I think that @Naftuli Tzvi Kay is asking if it is possible to have access to the music downloaded from the play store elsewhere than in google play music.. Am i clear?

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded all my music to Google Play Music, and I want to configure the app to download _ALL_ of that music and keep everything synced to my device's storage for offline playback.

Answer (score 1):

If I have well understood your question, I will recommend you to have a look at [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98984/purchased-music-wont-play-without-wifi) where I have explained how to do what you want : sync your music on your local storage.

Comment: I'd have to do that for every artist, not a small task with over 200-300 artists, and I'd have to remember to do it every time I added a new artist.

Comment: go in your Goggle play music -> playlist -> free and purchased -> an then click on the little arrow and it will sync all your music

Comment: "this question" is 404 here; possibly the question has been deleted?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: my music was not purchased with Google but uploaded via the app.

Comment: So go in playlist -> last uploads -> an click on the arrow, I think it will sync your music. If not, I don't see how.. Or I maybe don't understand your question..

Answer (score 0):

There is an auto playlist called "Recently added", if you sync that it will contain your entire library.

Comment: Please link the app

Comment: No, it won't. It will sync last 500 songs added into the library. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Go to the play music desktop site
- Step 2: click the 3 bar menue on the top left
- Step 3: Scroll down until you find "Download Library"
- Step 4: click download
- Step 5: save the files wherever you want them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct answer, as it is *not* *sync* and it could be hard work. But probably best what man can do.

You can download for offline use every playlist available on the device (Download in context menu of the playlist). Problem is that playlist is limited to size of thousand songs. So what you can do:

- if having 500 songs or less => download `Last added` songs playlist
- if having 1000 songs or less => `Shuffle all` songs and then save that queue as playlist => download the playlist
- if having more, more work is needed:

  - Use web UI of Play Music, switch to all songs and create one playlist for every ~1000 songs. You can choose one song by click, and last by shift+click. Then right click "Add to playlist/new".
  - On phone, download playlists.
  - Also choose of download for Last added playlist, so new (up to 500 new) added songs are downloaded automatically.
  - Periodically add songs of `Last added` playlist into other non-full playlist selected for download. You have to do this at least every 500 new songs – so probably not so often. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I just found a solution that is not so clean but works. Using the web interface, in the tag where there are all your songs you can select packs of them using shift-click an add them to a play list.(you have to do groups of 1000 songs because is the maximum) then you have a free play list containing all your library is easy to sync in your phone.